# Makefile error in WSL Ubuntu : no rule to make target

Tags: c++, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get the following error :

> make : *** no rule to make target obj/Divers.o, needed by main. Stop

Here is what my makefile look like :

```
IDIR = include
ODIR = obj
SDIR = src
BDIR = bin

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -I$(IDIR)

PROG = main

_DEP = Divers.h ArbresSyntaxiques.h
DEP = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEP))

_OBJ = Divers.o ArbresSyntaxiques.o Main.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

.PHONY: run all remake clean delete

all: $(PROG)

run : all 
    ./$(PROG)

$(PROG) : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lm

$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SDIR)/%.c $(DEP)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean :
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o

delete : clean
    rm $(PROG)
```

Finally my folder is structured like this :

```
include :
    ArbresSyntaxiques.h
    Divers.h
obj : (Empty)
src :
    AbresSyntaxiques.cpp
    Divers.cpp
    Main.cpp
makefile
```

Comment: `$(SDIR)/%.c` shouldn't this be `$(DIR)/%.cpp`?

Comment: @kiner_shah You're right forgot to change it.

Comment: Just made the change and i'm still getting an error just not for Divers.o anymore but for AbresSyntaxiques.o. The error is still the same.

Comment: Where is AbresSyntaxiques.o file created? Maybe it's in some different directory.

Comment: It was a typo error in the name of the cpp. It now works. Thanks for your help. Can't believe i didn't see these mistakes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @kiner_shah mentioned under the comments.

To compile C++ instead of C, the file extension obviously needs to be either `.cpp` or `.c++` on the following line `$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SDIR)/%.c $(DEP)`

I also had a typo in what of my cpp files' name